# Beginner question OOP: What is wrong with this increment on object array

Tags: c#, oop

I am just starting out with OOP and trying to understand the code below. Why is book2 object changing its value even though i am not defining it to something els just using that object to define the values of the objects in books array.

```
Book[] books = new Book[5];
Book book2 = new Book("test", "test1", 800);

for (int i = 0; i < books.Length; i++)
{
    books[i] = book2;
    Console.WriteLine(books[i].pages);
    books[i].pages += 10;
}
```

Is there something fundemental i have missed about objects? In my thinking this code should return 800, 5 times.

Just and explination how my thinking is flawed

Comment: Welcome to SO! This line of code: `books[i] = book2` changes the pointer of each element of the array to `book2`'s pointer. Essentially after that every element in the array is 'book2'. Try changing it to: `books[i] = new Book("test", "test1", 500);`

Comment: "Why is book2 object changing its value" - because you're doing so here: `books[i].pages += 10`. Basically it looks like you need to read up on how *reference types* work in C# - my (old but still valid) article is a reasonable starting point: https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/references.html

Comment: You are assigning the same `Book` object with the values test, test1 and 800 to all of the Book array elements inside your for loop and also changing the number of pages each time - meaning all of the entries point to the same object, which has its pages increased 5 times in the end.

Comment: lots of people giving good answers. but just to help conceptualise it. pretend we had a book in the real world. Theres just one of them and we pass it from person to person and ask them to write 10 pages in the book. each time we pass it to the next person they get the same book. if you ask all five people which book they are working on they will all point to the same book. You could take a new book and give them each their own. They could take their own copy and ask somebody else to sign it, etc. This is the concept of a reference type. Not all c# types are reference but it's common.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C# there are two types of objects in terms of memory representation, with the terms "value type" and "reference type".

**Value types** hold their value by instance, and this type is underlying most simple types (integral numeric types, floating-point numeric types, *bool* and *char*)

**Reference types** are (simplified) "anything else". Precisely said, definied by using any of these keywords: *class*, *interface*, *delegate*, *record*, *dynamic*. Also the build-in types *object*, *dynamic* and *string* are reference types.

The reason for this difference can be abbreviated by performance. While it is quite efficient to store the data bits of number, for complex objects instead a reference is used, which can be thought of as the "number of the memory register" used to store the main data. This "register number" can be handled quite effiently.

As you defined `class Book {...}`, you created a reference type variable. Your for-loop is assigning each books[] item the "value" book2, they all are initialized to point to the same piece of memory. Thus modifying one of these instances will in turn modify modify all of them.

If you need independent instances, then you have assign a value including the new keyword, like fabian showed earlier. Eventually you will find that having a "copy constructor" can be quite handy (like in `var anotherBook = new Book(existingBook);`)

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning the same object reference to all positions in the array. So the Page += 10 that you are doing is being done always on the same object.

That is why you see 800, 810, 820 etc.